# solspace freeform alternative

Tags: ee2, solspace-freeform

I just installed [Freeform 4.0.12](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/) and it seems to be completely broken I cant edit or create forms fields or notifications.
If I try to create a form there inst a submit button.

If I try to create a field or notification this text appears at the end on the cp page.
 "PHRhYmxlIGNsYXNzPSJtYWluVGFibGUgcGFkVGFibGUgZnJlZWZvcm1fdGFibGUgaGVhZGxlc3MiIHN0eWxlPSJ3aWR0aDoxMDAlOyI+Cjx0Ym9keT4KPHRyPgo8dGQ+PGxhYmVsIGZvcj0iYWxsb3dlZF91cGxvYWRfY291bnQiPkFsbG93ZWQgdXBsb2FkIGNvdW50PC9sYWJlbD48ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJzdWJ0ZXh0Ij5NYXhpbXVtIHF1YW50aXR5IG9mIGZpbGVz"

Is there an alternative to freeform for EE2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as though you did not get all the files uploaded correctly. Try deleting the `/system/expressionengine/third_party/freeform` and `/themes/third_party/freeform` folders and upload them again from scratch.

What version of EE?